# vb.net form popup - close without unload?

Tags: vb.net, userform

In a configuration application I have, I created 2 forms.  The main form and a popup form for settings. Both forms are just typical forms, no real difference except in size.

When I popup the 'settings form', it is great the first time - all settings are there from the database (I load a bunch of settings into textboxes and checkboxes from SQL Server).  However, if I use the 'x' to close that popup, all those settings do not persist.

I would like to persist these settings in that form so that I don't have to reload them every time.  How can I make the form NOT unload when hitting the 'x'?  Or am I thinking the wrong way?

Comment: are you responding to the form close event to save the settings?

Comment: Where do you want to persist your settings? Database, user hard drive, cloud? For how long do you want them to be persisted? Until user closes the application, or longer than that? Please describe in detail (by editing your question).

Answer (score 0):

Try to just hide the form to persist the info you want to remain.

```
Private Sub myForm_Closing(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs) Handles MyBase.Closing
        Me.Hide()

        e.Cancel = True
    End Sub
```

But frankly, you can store the values of the settings in a class once and call them anytime you want without worrying.

Answer (score 0):

I think I would collect the settings values into a structure in your main form and send that to the settings dialog each time it is shown.  You collect the settings from SQL once in your main form and maintain them in a public variable structure you can send to the dialog as needed.

Answer (score 0):

If you create a new form object and show that, the form object will persist even after the form is closed.

```
Dim NewForm2 As New Form2
NewForm2.Show
```